# Create List with two items e.g. List<String, Integer>

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I would like to create a List which contains a String file path and an Integer (the int stores the position of the filepath).

I will end up with a list of for example 100 items, could be more or could be less.

I would then like to split this List into 5 smaller lists.

I need to store the int too, as when the Lists will be split into the smaller ones, I need to also store its correct position from the original large list.

For example, here is a list with 10 items

abc, 0
bgs, 1
dwd, 2
th, 3
ht, 4
hth, 5
ef, 6
fe, 7
fe, 8
fef, 9

After splitting, it would look like:

abc, 0
bgs, 1

dwd, 2
th, 3

ht, 4
hth, 5

ef, 6
fe, 7

fe, 8
fef, 9

I looked at using a hashmap, but I couldn't find an example of how to split it.

After it is split, I need to retrieve both values from each element, e.g. I will loop through each List and use 'abc' and '0' etc etc

Comment: 1. Why do you need to split a list / map?

Comment: as I want to send each to its own AsyncTask.  Not sure if it will work but rather than send one big list to one Async task, I want to break it down and call 5 AsyncTasks running in parallel..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a small class to hold your data:

```
public class ListItem {
  public String path;
  public int pos;
}
```

Then use a List< ListItem >.

Comment: could you show me how to add items and then retrieve the items from this custom list in a loop?

Comment: `List< ListItem > mylist = new ArrayList<ListItem>(); //fill it for ( ListItem item : myList ) { System.out.println( "path:"+item.path+" at pos " + item.pos);}`

Comment: I am having trouble adding e.g. mylist.add (ListItem)  - how do I add the string and the int?

Comment: create a constructor for your ListItem: `public ListItem(String path, int pos) {this.path=path;this.pos=pos;}` then you can do `myList.add( new ListItem( "somepath", 1));`

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, I was doing it like this:  ListItem imgItem = new ListItem();
                            imgItem.pos = loopCount;
                            imgItem.path=fileInfo.path;

Answer (score 0):

Use [std::pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/) for the string and integer
After that create a list of pairs:

```
List<Pair<String, Integer>>
```

then use [list.splice](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/splice/)
to create the new lists.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that contains the indexes:

```
public void MyElement {
    private String s;
    private int n;
    private int index;
}
```

Use Guava [`Lists.partition`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition%28java.util.List,%20int%29) to then split your list.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a Map, get it's EntrySet and iterate it.